# Distance to the average of the next two prime numbers

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Suppose we have a sequence \$P\$. Every element \$P_n\$ represents the distance between the \$n^{th}\$ prime number and the average of the next two prime numbers.

For example, \$P_1\$ would be the distance between the first prime number (2) and the average of the next two prime numbers (3 and 5), so
\$P_1 = \frac{3+5}{2} - 2 = 2\$. Similarly, \$P_2 = \frac{5+7}{2} - 3 = 3\$.

### Input

Your input is an integer \$n\$. You may assume \$n>0\$.

### Output

Your task is to print out the sequence \$P\$ up to \$n\$, starting from \$P_1\$. You can format your output however you like as long as every element is clearly separated.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest number of bytes wins.
- You can assume that every computed number will be within the limits of the language you choose, so no need to worry about how big \$n\$ or \$P_n\$ can get.

### Test cases

```
Input            Output
n = 1            2
n = 2            2, 3
n = 5            2, 3, 4, 5, 4
n = 10           2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 5
```

(If you're curious, this sequence is [A305748](https://oeis.org/A305748)!)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'd recommend using the standard [tag:sequence] rules (which can be found in the tag wiki/"learn more..."), which allow a few other output formats, like an infinite iterator or just the Nth term. Other than that, this looks like a great question!

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to AndrovT*

```
ƛ⇧ṡ‹ǎḣṁε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm+KHp+G5oeKAuceO4bij4bmBzrUiLCIiLCIxMCJd) | [7 bytes to output the nth number](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLih6fhuaHigLnHjuG4o+G5gc61IiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) | [9 bytes as an infinite list by emanresu A](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnAzbMabw7crwr3OtSIsIiIsIiJd)

**Explantion:**

```
ƛ⇧ṡ‹ǎḣṁε
ƛ           Implicitly take input, convert it to a range and open mapping lambda :P
 ⇧ṡ         Range between n and n+2
   ‹ǎ       Decrement and get the respective prime (1-indexed)
     ḣṁε    Head extract; push mean and get the abs difference
```

Comment: [9](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnAzbMabw7crwr3OtSIsIiIsIiJd) as an infinite list

Comment: [8](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm+KHp+G5oeKAuceO4bij4bmBzrUiLCIiLCIxMCJd) ([7](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLih6fhuaHigLnHjuG4o+G5gc61IiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==) to output nth number ([6](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLih6fhuaHHjuG4o+G5gc61IiwiIiwiOSJd) 0-indexed))

Comment: @AndrovT how do you always manage to golf every single answer of mine

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

Returns a space-separated string.

```javascript
f=(n,q=p=3,r=2,x=p++)=>n?--x?f(n,q,r,p%~x?x:p++):(p+q)/2-r+' '+f(n-1,p,q):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBDsIgEEDRvadwY2DCoILphmTKWZpajKaBgRrDqldHuzTdvv9fw2dYxvLkt47pPrUWSEbMxHTDQhYrsVJAffRaVx@2hgX5tFZf3ZacZJXhYnVR4ijU79AGGTM4IdqY4pLm6TynhwzSABz@xe6k24m5ArQv)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (               // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                //   n = number of terms to generate
  q =               //   q = previous confirmed prime
  p = 3,            //   p = current prime candidate
  r = 2,            //   r = penultimate confirmed prime
  x = p++           //   x = divisor (post-increment p here)
) =>                //
n ?                 // if we still have some terms to generate:
  --x ?             //   decrement x; it it's not zero:
    f(              //     do a recursive call:
      n, q, r,      //       pass n, q and r unchanged
      p % ~x ?      //       if x + 1 does not divide p:
        x           //         keep using x as the divisor
      :             //       else (p is composite):
        p++         //         reset the divisor to p and increment p
    )               //     end of recursive call
  :                 //   else (p is prime):
    (p + q) / 2 - r //     append (p + q) / 2 - r, which is the next
    +               //     term of the sequence by definition
    ' ' +           //     followed by a space
    f(              //     followed by the result of a recursive call:
      n - 1,        //       decrement n
      p, q          //       set (q, r) = (p, q)
    )               //     end of recursive call
:                   // else:
  ''                //   stop
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÌÅpü3ε`+;α
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cM/h1oLDe4zPbU3Qtj638f9/QwMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wz2HWwsO7zE@tzVB2/rcxv@1Ov@jDXWMdEx1DA1iAQ).

Or alternatively:

```
>ÝØDü2ÅA¦α
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//z7DncOYRMO8MsOFQcKmzrH//zEw) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX/dnk/IiDihpIgIj95/z7DncOYRMO8MsOFQcKmzrH/LP9bMSwyLDUsMTBd).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ì           # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 2
 Åp         # Pop and push the first input+2 amount of prime numbers
   ü3       # Get all overlapping triplets of this list
     ε      # Map each triplet to:
      `     #  Pop and push the three values in the triplet separated to the stack
       +    #  Add the top two together
        ;   #  Halve this sum
         α  #  Get the absolute difference with the third one
            # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)

>           # Increase the (implicit) input-integer by 1
 Ý          # Pop and push a list in the range [0,input+1]
  Ø         # Get the 0-based index for each of these values
   D        # Duplicate this list
    ü2      # Get all overlapping pairs of the copy
      ÅA    # Get the arithmetic mean of each inner pair
        ¦   # Remove the first one
         α  # Get the absolute difference between the values in the two lists 
            # (the trailing additional item of the prime-list is discarded)
            # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
↑Ẋ₁İp
≠⁰½+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9odXNr///ihpHhuorigoHEsHAK4omg4oGwwr0r////MTA)

```
≠⁰½+    # helper function with 3 args:
≠       # absolute difference between
 ⁰      #   first arg and
  ½     #   half
   +    #   the sum of 
        #   the (implicit) other 2 args
        
↑Ẋ₁İp   # main program:
↑       # get the first input elements of
 Ẋ₁     #   applying helper function ₁ to groups of 3
   İp   #   from the infinite list of primes
```

Same byte-count to output the `n`-th element (by swapping the initial `↑` for `!` [index]), or one byte less to output the infinite sequence ([9 bytes](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9odXNr///huorigoHEsHAK4omg4oGwwr0r//8), by omitting the initial `↑`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `grouping.extras math.primes`, 46 bytes

```factor
[ 2 + nprimes [ + 2/ - abs ] 3 clump-map ... ]
```

[image: running the above code in Factor's REPL]

Could be 42 bytes without the restrictive IO.

```
2 + nprimes       ! get the first input+2 primes
[                 ! begin clump-map
    + 2/          ! the average of the next two primes
    - abs         ! subtracted by the current prime
] 3 clump-map     ! map over every three elements with overlapping
...               ! prettyprint a sequence of any length to stdout
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>111</s> 106 bytes

```java
n->{for(int a=2,b=3,c,k=5;n>0;){for(c=1;k%++c>0;);if(k++==c){System.out.println((b+c)/2-a);a=b;b=c;n--;}}}
```

Prints the results on separated newlines to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZCxasMwEIb3PMURKEhIdmOXLBHK0ilD0iFjyCBf5OLYkY0lpxSjZ3dl1@nUQheB/vt09@mu6q6i66UcsFLWwl4Vpl8AFMbpNleo4TBeAe51cQEkIQdDRYj8IhzWKVcgHMCAHEy07fO6nRglU57JF468lGthtitBpxrKRJRPjOGYiCInJWNSIu2Pn9bpW1x3Lm7a0KEyhGQM6XMaKSqUzEQmUZgoEt77QYzDmy6rwvDZYRK8BX1ydKHB@@ms6Lf6w8lp616V1bABoz/GL57OfcJTvubJys8wwC8my51pOreBJXv0mFbwF/3WuYDbwP9gJkbyn7dzzU8L9sMX)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{              // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  int a=2,b=3,    //  Previous two primes, starting at hard-coded 2 and 3
      c,          //  Current prime, uninitialized
      k=5;        //  Prime-loop integer, starting at the third prime 5
  for(;n>0;){     //  Loop as long as the input `n` is not 0 yet:
    for(c=1;      //   Reset `c` to 1
        k%++c>0;);//   Keep increasing `c` as long as `c` is NOT divisible by `k`
    if(k++==c){   //   If `k` and `c` are now equal (which means `c` is a prime number):
                  //   (and increase `k` by 1 afterwards for the next iteration with `k++`)
      System.out.println((b+c)/2-a);
                  //    Print (b+c)//2-a with trailing newline
      a=b;b=c;    //    Then set a=b and b=c for the next iteration
      n--;}}}     //    And decrease `n` by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <del>21</del> 20 bytes

```
3(-~-:)`+/\p:@i.@+&2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBWEO3TtdKM0FbP6bAyiFTz0Fbzeh/anJGvkKagrHRfwA)

- `+` `&` `2`: Add 2 to *n*.
- And then (`@`, composition), `i.`: Make a list of the first *n*+2 nonnegative integers.
- And then (`@`, composition), `p:`: Get the prime numbers of those indices.
- `3` ...`\`: Apply the inside verb to each three consecutive prime numbers.

  - `(-~-:)` `` ` `` `+` `/`: Insert the two subverbs between the prime numbers, turning `p q r` into `p (-~-:) (q + r)`.

    - `q + r` adds (`+`) `q` and `r`.
    - `(-~-:)` is a hook; it halves (`-:`) the sum of `q` and `r`, and then subtracts (`-`) `p` from the result; `~` swaps the operands from their usual order.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 95 bytes

```
\d+
__¶$&$*#___
#(#*(_+))
$2¶$1_
}+`\b(__+)\1+$
$&_
M!&`\b_+¶_+¶_+
(_+)¶\1(_+)¶\1(\2(_+))\4
$.3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbKz7@0DYVNRUt5fj4eC5lDWUtjXhtTU0uFSOgsGE8V612QkySRjxQLMZQW4VLRS2ey1dRDSgWr31oGwRzgXQc2hZjCKdjjMCGxJhwqegZ//9vaAAA) Explanation:

```
\d+
__¶$&$*#___
```

On the first pass, convert the input to `2,n,3` where `n` is a unary run of `#`s while the primes are unary using `_`s.

```
#(#*(_+))
$2¶$1_
```

Replace `n,p` with `p,n-1,p+1`.

```
+`\b(__+)\1+$
$&_
```

Increment the last value until it becomes prime.

```
}`
```

Repeat the above until `n=0`.

```
M!&`\b_+¶_+¶_+
```

Extract overlapping windows of three primes.

```
(_+)¶\1(_+)¶\1(\2(_+))\4
$.3
```

Match each set of three primes as `\1, \1+\2, \1+\2+\4+\4` and calculate `\2+\4` in decimal; `\1+\2+\4` is the average of the second and third primes so `\2+\4` is the difference between that and the first prime.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 92 bytes

```
(`take`((zipWith3(\x y z->div(x+y)2-z)=<<tail)=<<tail)[x|x<-[2..],all((0/=).mod x)[2..x-1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and f(n-1)+[(g(n+1)+g(n+2))//2-g(n)]or[]
g=lambda n,i=1,p=1:n and-~g(n-p%i,i+1,p*i*i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxCoAwEAR7X5FGuDMJGu2EvEQsIhI90DNIGhu/HiOC1Q7LTLjienCXkreb26fZCe5ZOJ6FB9YG5QALsMzwTotY163OiONxDmOx/JUia1Sw5qv1nR0dSlIk811RRZjCSRzBg2kQ0wM)

I couldn't find a better way than using a helper function, `g`, (stolen from [Lynn's amazing answer on the tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152433/114446)) to get the n<sup>th</sup> prime.

However, with default [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules, it would be [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYoxDsIwDEV3TuEFyW4SVS5bpZwEGFK1SS0VN4o6lIWrhzAw/af3fn4f6663Gv2jbuE1zQF0xIRqmMxvBqK@H1xDuiT/v1jxbLPnUSHo7D4tu3wVK6bpTjqhmovogfeIJ0HcC5wgCiVoWpAtMNOT6hc).

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
(#2+#3)/2-#&@@Prime[#+{0,1,2}]&~Array~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X0PZSFvZWFPfSFdZzcEhoCgzNzVaWbvaQMdQx6g2Vq3OsagosbJOWe0/UCqvREHfIV3fQaEaKKljqmNoUPv/PwA)

Comment: Completely based on another answer without citing the source.

Comment: @lesobrod Hi! welcome to CDCC and thanks for the downvote! If you keep posting on this site you'll see that there are trivial things thal we all use all the time. This doesn't mean that we steal these things from other answers. (#2+#3)/2-# is trivial. I tried to help you by golfing your answer without changing your way of thinking (using partition). I also believe that answers that are different should be posted as separate answers. For such easy challenges as this one, I believe that my answer is different.It's good that u undeleted your answer so that everyone can enjoy both answers. peace

Comment: Sorry i was wrong =(  
I'm going through hard times and CDCC is kinda self-help. I will react more thoughtfully. 
It's impossible to change now vote, until u edit answer. I'll do it if i can.

Comment: @lesobrod don't worry about the vote. I am sure you'll have fun here! I can assure you that this is a very nice community and you will learn crazy things about any language!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹ηＷ‹ⅉθ«≦⊕η¿⬤υ﹪ηκ«Ｆ‹⁴η⟦Ｉ⁻⊘⁺η↨υ⁰§υ±²⟧⊞υη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY69DsIwDITn9ik8OlKQALExFRYqUdQVIYbQGhIRUsgPICGePSTAZp/vu3Mnhe0GoWOszTX4TbgcyOKNzcvKOXUyOOEg0/aQShPgmpzDLTION8bgVRaNuP6NteksXch46n9IoY6AldYYODRDH/SAksOZ/cDiONh/3iz7GbRWGY@7pXAeG2WCw5XQd@qx1WlO6EI4ymHjFMGh8rXp6ZmFDZ2EJ5wmne1zc9EGJ/Pl@8e7fMc4GcfRXX8A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start looking for primes after `1`.

```
Ｗ‹ⅉθ«
```

Repeat until `n` results have been obtained.

```
≦⊕η
```

Increment the candidate prime.

```
¿⬤υ﹪ηκ«
```

If it is indeed prime, then:

```
Ｆ‹⁴η
```

If it is at least the third prime, then...

```
⟦Ｉ⁻⊘⁺η↨υ⁰§υ±²⟧
```

... output the difference of the average with the previous prime with the prime before.

```
⊞υη
```

Add the prime to the list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)], 42 bytes

```
ListConvolve[{1,1,-2}/2,Prime@Range[#+2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yezuMQ5P68sP6csNbraUMdQR9eoVt9IJ6AoMzfVISgxLz01WlnbKDZW7T9QKK8kOi3aNDaWC8Y2NIiN/Q8A)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1nZSNdIWc3BwSGgKDM31cGxqCixMlpZWddQTadaWce4NlbfSO0/UC6vJDot2jQ2lgvGNjSIjf0PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
3Ḷ+)ÆNḋ-,.,.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/44Y5t2pqH2/we7ujW1dHT0fv//7@hAQA)

This *has* to be possible in 11 bytes if a hardcoded dot product ties everything else I've come up with...

```
3Ḷ              [0, 1, 2]
  +             plus
   )            each [1 .. n], individually.
    ÆN          Get the x'th prime for each x in that matrix,
      ḋ         then return each row's dot product with
       -,.,.    [-1, 0.5, 0.5].
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 49 bytes

```raku
{(-*+(*+*)/2)(|grep(&is-prime,2..*)[^3+$++])xx$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkNXS1tDS1tLU99IU6MmvSi1QEMts1i3oCgzN1XHSE9PSzM6zlhbRVs7VrOiQiW@9r@1QnFipUKahpGB5n8A)

Without the requirement for preceding elements, this could output the nth element for 42 bytes:

```raku
-*+(*+*)/2 o{grep(&is-prime,2..*)[^3+$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfV0tbQ0tbS1PfSCG/Or0otUBDLbNYt6AoMzdVx0hPT0szOs5YWyU@tva/tUJxYqVCmoZKvKZCWn6RQpyhwX8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>53</s> 47 bytes

```
(#3+#2)/2-#&@@@Partition[Prime@Range[#+2],3,1]&
```

Thanks to @ZaMoC

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X0PZWFvZSFPfSFfZUM3BQVlN3yEgsagksyQzPy86oCgzN1XfISgxLz3VQUNZ20hTx1jHMFbtP1AiryQ6Ldo0NpYLxjY0iI39DwA)

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X0PZWFvZSFPfSFdZzcHBISCxqCSzJDM/LzqgKDM31SEoMS89NVpZ2yhWx1jHMFbtP1A4ryQ6Ldo0NpYLxjY0iI39DwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

### BSD/Linux command line, 52 bytes

Requirements:

- any Bourne-style shell;
- awk;
- the [`primes`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=primes&apropos=0&sektion=6) program from the classic BSD games collection ([`bsdgames`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bsdgames) package on Debian, Ubuntu and derivatives, [`bsd-games`](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/bsd-games/bsd-games/) on Fedora, …).

```
primes 2|awk '{a=b;b=c;c=$0;$0=(c+b)/2-a}a'|head -$1
```

Try it online: there seems to be a bug in the version of awk on TIO which causes it to print blanks when printing `$0` (implicitly or explicitly) and `$0` is numeric. The version in my answer does work on my machines. Here's [modified code with a workaround](https://tio.run/##yy7O@P@/oCgzN7VYwagmsTxbQb060TbJOsk22TrZVsXAWsXAViNZO0lT30g3UUmpNlG9JiM1MUVBV8Xw////hgYA) — obviously the workaround for the bug on TIO increases the length (by two bytes: an extra `""`).

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 188 bytes

```
let x=Seq.initInfinite
let p n=n=2||Seq.forall(fun c->n%c<>0)[2..n-1]
let f n=x(fun i->n+i+1)|>Seq.find p
let s n=x(fun i->i+2)|>Seq.where p|>Seq.map(fun p->(f p+(f p|>f))/2-p)|>Seq.take n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BasMwDIbvfQpRKMSkzhrDLsti2LGw246lhyyzqViqaI7DevC7Z7GTwC6WrP/7ZGwH2fbOTFNnPDzqD/NTIKE/k43F7OKYgWqqVQgxtb1rui6zI0ErNR3aV30SF1UUJMtrwu2MPxKAM5BjXoqgk4r0BZyY4T@DuVqJ35txBni53BtOBEudWeA8HkFbIZ6U5FXwzbcBmi5lparnqjxdd0HDKkOyabx/GgdSQ7a0x/j4MlxZ37/j4IXY3PnfbpEzJB79EfrRz1XELeyQvCXYn2P0Aoe3LY79HpKxCdMf)

Didn't think it would end up so big, to be honest. I wonder if my approach is maybe wrong... but it's all functional, stateless, and inefficent.

Anyway, a brief explanation:

`x` is a shorthand for `Seq.initInfinite`, which creates endless, lazy-evaluated sequences.
`p n` determines if a number `n` is prime.
`f n` gets the next prime number after `n`.
`s n` is the main sequence function. First it creates a sequence of primes, then for each of them, gets the next prime and next-next prime, and calculates the average. Finally, it takes the first `n` elements in the sequence.